# how to temporary lock android app for certain time?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi guys I need some help/pointers for temporary locking my current app that I have. For e.g. my app has this main activity to add items, the user needs to key in the correct passcode before adding. If after 3 times of wrong passcode entered the the lock will be activated to disable the user from using the app for a time being.

I have some initial thoughts of doing it but I don't think its possible. Since I have my own passcode dialog screen, then I will have a counter for wrong passcode(< 4) after that open another dialog with countdown timer. And this is where I think its not possible because if the user were to kill the app and relaunch I believe the "lock dialog screen" will be gone also

Comment: Maybe you could store the amount of failed attempts and when they were made in the SharedPreferences?

Comment: I do not know what your app is, but even if your user uninstall the app (the security wont matter at all because all the previous datas are remove and you have nothing to hide).

Comment: @matanso thanks, I will go look into that and see how can i do it. Sorry I am a newbie

Comment: @Enzokie thanks for the reply. Yep I am aware that uninstall or clear data, will swipe everything, I am wondering if it is possible to add this additional security measure to it.

Answer (score 0):

Could try this way:

- store the input history by inserting them in file or Sqlite database or some other storage system.
- For example, when user enter a wrong input you could fetch and increment the last error counter. 
  After reaching a threshold value (for your case 3 times consecutive wrong input) store the time of last wrong input and save a flag to halt application till a specific time.
- each time you tired to start your application check the value of flag and last wrong input time. If suspension time is over then undo the flag to default.

Comment: thanks for the reply! So I am thinking that if user did not quit the app, the "lock dialog screen" will be opened, so if user quit and relaunch my main activity will check for the flag so if the time is not over yet I will display some error message. will there be any problem?

Comment: You could Implement as you required.